# php problem having the sum of values in a loop

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm new in php and got stuck doing a loop.

I have the following:

- an array containing 0 or not named `$receivers`.
- another array containing total of receivers which is a number, named `$totalreceivers`.
- a function querying a table with the id, returning 0 or number, named `status()`.

I want to loop through each `status()` of the receivers and show the sum at the end. I couldn't get it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I tried:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalreceivers; $i++)
{
    $status = status($receivers[$i]);
    foreach ($totalreceivers as $value)
        $status = status($receivers[$i]); 
    echo "the sum of receiver having status different than 0 is";
    echo count($status);
}

function status($id)
{
    global $dbhost;
    global $dbuser;
    global $dbpass;
    global $dbname;
    global $d1;

    $q2 = mysql_query("select * from user where id ='$id' AND subscription_end_date IS NULL", $d1);

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2))
        $rowservice = $row2['value'];
    return $rowservice;
}
```

Comment: you did not addresses your problem in a good way. please try to format your question so that it could address your problem

Comment: You can do the sum within MySQL per *one* query; Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this task by letting MySQL do more of the work for you.

You have an array `$receivers` which presumably contains id's for subscribers to (receivers of) something. (I may use receiver and subscriber interchangeably.)

The `status()` function retrieves from the database the `value` for each receiver where the `subscription_end_date` is null. I am going to assume that there is only one row per subscriber because you only return the last result via the variable `$rowservice`.

It's unclear from your code if you want a count of receivers with a `value` other than 0, or if you want a sum of all non-zero values. The question then is:

- Do you want to know how many subscribers have nonzero values? or,
- Do you want to know the sum of all values for subscribers with nonzero values?

Fortunately both of these can be easily found:

**How many receivers have non-zero values?**

```
$allreceivers = implode(',', $receivers);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_receivers
    FROM user
    WHERE subscription_end_date IS NULL
    AND value != 0
    AND id IN ($allreceivers);";
$result = mysql_query($query, $d1);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total_receivers = $row['total_receivers'];

echo "The number of receivers having status (value) other than 0 is $total_receivers";
```

**What is the sum of all receiver values?**

```
$allreceivers = implode(',', $receivers);
$query = "SELECT SUM(value) AS receiver_value_sum
    FROM user
    WHERE subscription_end_date IS NULL
    AND id IN ($allreceivers);";
$result = mysql_query($query, $d1);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$receiver_value_sum = $row['receiver_value_sum'];

echo "The sum of receiver values is $receiver_value_sum";
```

Comment: You're welcome @user888300; don't forget to [vote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up). :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple things in your code don't really make sense. First, you're *trying* to iterate through `$totalreceivers` twice, one loop being nested in the other. I doubt that's what you want so you should get rid of one of them. And your first loop has a bad expression: to iterate through `$totalreceivers` in your first `for` loop, you need to have your testing expression go against the number of elements in the array and not the array itself (can use count()): `for ($i = 0; $i < count($totalreceivers); $i++)`.

Second, you're resetting the value of `$status` each time you call `status()` in your loop. To add to it, use the `+=` operator: `$status += status($receivers[$i]);`

Third, you're doing the same in status() function with `$rowservice`; resetting it each iteration of that `while` loop. Either set it once, or sum it up.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like you are just overwriting "$status" on each iteration. Before the loop starts, set $status to an empty array and then add to it on each iteration. For example:

```
    $status = array();
    foreach ( $totalreceivers as $value)
    {
    $status[] = status($receivers[$i]); 
    }
    echo count($status);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to outline some possible problems with your code below:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalreceivers; $i++) { //This open bracket has no end bracket
/*I assume total receivers is the number of receivers; if that is the case, it shouldn't be an array, but merely a value.*/
            $status = status($receivers[$i]); 
/*I think you should define the status function before you call it; also, if you are just calling the status function for each value of $receivers, why don't you just do a foreach($receivers as $value) loop, like you did below with $totalreceivers. */
         foreach ( $totalreceivers as $value)
/*I'm not sure what $totalreceivers is.  You said its an array containing total number of receivers; again, I would think this would be a single value, and not an array*/
        {
        $status = status($receivers[$i]); 
/*looks like you're calling the status function again*/
        }
            echo "the sum of receiver having status different thant 0 is";  echo count($status); 
/* $status at this point would count the value from row2 for the last value in $receivers, and not a count of array values.  Perhaps you could do $status[] = status($receivers[$i]), and then count($status) to save each value to an array, then count the elements. */

function status($id){
global $dbhost;
global $dbuser;
global $dbpass;
global $dbname;
/* The values above aren't used in the function; you may want to connect to the database outside of the function, before the foreach loop. */
global $d1 ;

$q2 = mysql_query("select * from user where id ='$id' AND subscription_end_date IS NULL",$d1);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)){
$rowservice = $row2['value'];
}
return $rowservice;
}
/*the rest looks good*/
```